# script タグの type="text/javascript" の有無による違い

Tags: javascript, html5

下記コードでscript type="text/javascript"とやるのとscriptとでやるのでは結果が同じになりますが、両者はどのように使い分けるのでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>あいうえお商店</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <body>
  <p id="msg">siueo</p>
  <script>
   var e = document.getElementById('msg');
   e.textContent = 'hello';
   e.style.color = 'red';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML5より前のバージョンでは`<script>`タグ内をJavaScriptとして処理させるためには、そのスクリプトがJavaScriptであると指定するために`type="text/javascript"`が必要でしたが、HTML5から`type`の指定が無い場合はデフォルトでJavaScriptとして処理されるので、違いはありません。
ちなみに文書型宣言を`<!DOCTYPE html>`にするとHTML5です。